Lindeberg central limit theorem by the Lindeberg swapping trick
(Lindeberg central limit theorem) Let ${k_n}$ be a sequence of natural numbers going to infinity in ${n}$. For each natural number ${n}$, let ${X_{1,n},\dots,X_{k_n,n}}$ be jointly independent real random variables of mean zero and finite variance. Let ${\sigma_n}$ be defined by $\displaystyle \sigma_n^2 := \sum_{i=1}^{k_n} {\bf Var}(X_{i,n})$, and assume that ${\sigma_n>0}$ for all ${n}$. If one assumes the Lindeberg condition that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sigma_n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{k_n} {\bf E}( |X_{i,n}|^2 1_{|X_{i,n}| > \varepsilon \sigma_n} ) \rightarrow 0$ as ${n \rightarrow \infty}$ for any ${\varepsilon > 0}$, then show that the random variables $\displaystyle {\frac{X_{1,n}+\dots+X_{k_n,n}}{\sigma_n}}$ converge in distribution to a random variable with the normal distribution ${N(0,1)}$.
To generalize the argument presented in Math 275A note 4, we first assume finite third moment and then use truncation to remove such hypothesis.
Attempt: We want $\displaystyle {\bf E} G( \frac{X_{1,n}+\dots+X_{k_n,n}}{\sigma_n} ) \rightarrow {\bf E} G(N)$ as ${n \rightarrow \infty}$ for any smooth compactly supported functions ${G: {\bf R} \rightarrow {\bf R}}$, where $N \sim N(0 ,1)$.
For each $n$, let $Y_{i, n} \sim N(0, \alpha_{i,n}^2), 1 \leq i \leq k_n$ be a row of normal variables such that $(X_{i,n}, Y_{i,n})_{i=1}^{k_n}$ are jointly independent, where $\alpha_{i,n}^2 := {\bf E}|X_{i,n}|^2$. Since $\displaystyle {\bf E} G( \frac{Y_{1,n}+\dots+Y_{k_n,n}}{\sigma_n} ) \rightarrow {\bf E} G(N)$ as ${n \rightarrow \infty}$ (indeed we even have equality here), it suffices to show that
$\displaystyle {\bf E} G( \frac{X_{1,n}+\dots+X_{k_n,n}}{\sigma_n} ) - {\bf E} G( \frac{Y_{1,n}+\dots+Y_{k_n,n}}{\sigma_n} ) \rightarrow 0$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$. We first establish this claim under the additional simplifying assumption of finite third moment: ${\bf E}|X_{i,n}|^3 < \infty$ for all $n$ and $1 \leq i \leq k_n$. Consider the expression
$\displaystyle {\bf E} G( \frac{X_{1,n}+\dots+X_{k_n,n}}{\sigma_n} ) - {\bf E} G( \frac{X_{1,n}+\dots+X_{k_n-1,n}+Y_{k_n,n}}{\sigma_n} )$.
Writing $\displaystyle {Z := \frac{X_{1,n} + \dots + X_{k_n-1,n}}{\sigma_n}}$, we can write this as
$\displaystyle {\bf E} G( Z + \frac{1}{\sigma_n} X_{k_n,n} ) - {\bf E} G( Z + \frac{1}{\sigma_n} Y_{k_n,n} )$.
As ${G}$ is smooth and compactly supported, the first three derivatives of ${G}$ are bounded, leading to the Taylor approximation
$\displaystyle G( Z + \frac{1}{\sigma_n} X_{k_n,n} ) = G(Z) + \frac{1}{\sigma_n} G'(Z)X_{k_n,n} + \frac{1}{2\sigma_n^2} G^{''}(Z)X_{k_n,n}^2 + O(\frac{1}{\sigma_n^3} |X_{k_n,n}|^3)$
where the implied constant depends on ${G}$. Taking expectations, we conclude that
$\displaystyle {\bf E} G( Z + \frac{1}{\sigma_n} X_{k_n,n} ) = {\bf E}G(Z) + \frac{1}{\sigma_n} {\bf E}G'(Z) {\bf E}X_{k_n,n} + \frac{1}{2\sigma_n^2} {\bf E}G^{''}(Z) {\bf E}X_{k_n,n}^2 + O(\frac{1}{\sigma_n^3} {\bf E}|X_{k_n,n}|^3)$.
The same considerations apply after swapping ${X_{k_n,n}}$ with ${Y_{k_n,n}}$ (which also has a bounded third moment):
$\displaystyle {\bf E} G( Z + \frac{1}{\sigma_n} Y_{k_n,n} ) = {\bf E}G(Z) + \frac{1}{\sigma_n} {\bf E}G'(Z) {\bf E}Y_{k_n,n} + \frac{1}{2\sigma_n^2} {\bf E}G^{''}(Z) {\bf E}Y_{k_n,n}^2 + O(\frac{\alpha_{k_n,n}^3}{\sigma_n^3})$.
But by hypothesis, ${X_{k_n,n}}$ and ${Y_{k_n,n}}$ have matching moments to second order. Thus on subtraction:
$\displaystyle {\bf E} G( \frac{X_{1,n}+\dots+X_{k_n,n}}{\sigma_n} ) - {\bf E} G( \frac{X_{1,n}+\dots+X_{k_n-1,n} + Y_{k_n,n}}{\sigma_n} ) = O(\frac{1}{\sigma_n^3} (\alpha_{k_n,n}^3 + {\bf E}|X_{k_n,n}|^3))$
A similar argument (permuting the indices, and replacing some of the ${X_{i,n}}$ with ${Y_{i,n}}$) gives
$\displaystyle {\bf E} G( \frac{X_{1,n}+\dots+X_{i,n}+Y_{i+1,n}+\dots+Y_{k_n,n}}{\sigma_n} ) - {\bf E} G( \frac{X_{1,n}+\dots+X_{i-1,n}+Y_{i,n}+\dots+Y_{k_n,n}}{\sigma_n} ) = O(\frac{1}{\sigma_n^3} (\alpha_{k_n,n}^3 + {\bf E}|X_{k_n,n}|^3))$
for all ${1 \leq i \leq k_n}$. Summing the telescoping series, we conclude that
$\displaystyle {\bf E} G( \frac{X_{1,n}+\dots+X_{k_n,n}}{\sigma_n} ) - {\bf E} G( \frac{Y_{1,n}+\dots+Y_{k_n,n}}{\sigma_n} ) = O(\frac{k_n}{\sigma_n^3} (\alpha_{k_n,n}^3 + {\bf E}|X_{k_n,n}|^3))$
Question: Given the Lindeberg condition, it's still not clear immediately that the expression on the RHS of the above display goes to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. I wonder what is missing here?
Edit: There were some computation errors in summing the telescoping series, the question is now solved.
